# C Win32 API: Set state of check box

Tags: c, winapi

I would like a check box to be automatically unchecked when a certain value is reached. But I can't find an option to set the state of a check box

Comment: Where did you look in the documentation? Have you found the check box documentation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Send it a [`BM_SETCHECK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775989.aspx) message:

```
SendMessage(hWndOfCheckbox, BM_SETCHECK, BST_UNCHECKED, 0);
```

Alternatively, use the [Button_SetCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb849167.aspx) macro, that expands to the same call to `SendMessage` (but doesn't expose unused formal parameters):

```
Button_SetCheck(hWndOfCheckbox, BST_UNCHECKED);
```